# XMLHttpRequest calls not finishing before return statement so undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm attempting to count how many items total are in the database I'm querying. It's third party so it's cross domain XMLHttpRequests but I'm making the method in a Chrome Extension and the permissions bit in the manifest.json let's it work nicely.

The problem I seem to be having is this: I'm looping through a list of categories and counting the amount in each before the XMLHttpRequests are coming back from the external server. The methods are started by the press of a button of id="countButton". Here's the relevant javascript/jQuery:

```
//simple listener for the button
document.getElementById('countButton').addEventListener('click', function() runTotalCount()}, true);

//loops through a list of categories in a drop down with values 0-36
function runTotalCount(){
    var sum = 0;
    $('#categorySelect option').each(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        sum += retrieveCategoryCount(value);
        alert("New Sum = " + sum);
    });
    var total = "<p>Total items in Sum is " + sum + "</p>";
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = total;
}

//actually makes the request and sums the items count for each category
//the server response is a json with an alphabetized "items" per category
function retrieveCategoryCount(num){
    var sum = 0;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
            var str = xhr.responseText;
            alert("str = " + str);
            var json = $.parseJSON(str);
            alert("JSON = " + json);
            for(item in json.alpha){
                alert("items count = " + json.alpha[item].items);
                sum += json.alpha[item].items;
            }
        alert("Category Sum = " + sum);
        return sum;
        }
    }
    xhr.open(
        "GET",
        "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/category.json?category=" + num,
        true);
    xhr.send(null);
}
```

As it is the stuff within the `onreadystate` for `retrieveCategoryCount` never gets called because the XMLHttpRequests are still pending by the time the function finishes. On synchronous calls the `alert("Category Sum = " + sum);` returns the right number but then the function return just below it is NaN (I'd rather not hang up the browser though so asynchronous is what I'd prefer for a solution).

What needs to change to properly get the item count? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
I've also tried code for `retrieveCategoryCount` of this:

```
function retrieveCategoryCount(num){
    var sum = 0;
    $.getJSON("http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/category.json?category=" + num, function(data){
        for(item in data.alpha){
            alert("items count = " + data.alpha[item].items);
            sum += data.alpha[item].items;
        }
    alert("Category Sum = " + sum);
    return sum;
    });
}
```

The problem here is that the callback never gets run because the request is still pending by the time the value returned from the function is added to "sum".

Comment: There are so many things within your script that need to be fixed .... your using jQuery yet only leveraging its power in a couple of small places - with a bit of work you could at least half this code

Comment: Well any suggestions would be appreciated. I've used the $.ajax and $.getJSON in the past but I've already got other similar code working within the extension so I thought I'd keep things consistent.

Comment: I would perhaps suggest that you pass the server all of the options selected - perhaps in JSON or XML or plain text - let the server calculate the total and just run a single update to the screen

Comment: I have added an example answer - its not final code and will need to be updated ... the reason your code isnt working is because the AJAX call back is executed at a later date - the rest of the code within the function is executed immediately

Comment: I don't believe I can use POST for cross domain requests. The url I'm sending has `category=#` where the `#` is whatever category number you want (0-36). I don't think I can just POST an array to the server and have it know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code that should happen AFTER the async call completes into a callback function and pass that into your async function, then have it callback.

```
var sum = 0,
    setTotalCount = function(data){ 
        .. stuff to set the dom element based on callback
    };
$('#categorySelect option').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    retrieveCategoryCount(value, setTotalCount);
});


function retrieveCategoryCount(num, callback){
var sum = 0;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        var str = xhr.responseText;
        alert("str = " + str);
        var json = $.parseJSON(str);
        alert("JSON = " + json);
        for(item in json.alpha){
            alert("items count = " + json.alpha[item].items);
            sum += json.alpha[item].items;
        }
    alert("Category Sum = " + sum);
       callback(sum); // callback the function you passed in
    }
}
xhr.open(
    "GET",
    "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/category.json?category=" + num,
    true);
xhr.send(null);
}
```

Comment: When I tried this the only alert that ran was `alert("New Sum = " + sum);` since the request was still pending by the time the function called. Also: I'm somewhat new to javascript so I don't follow how the `callback(num);` at the end is supposed to solve this.

Comment: Well, at this point, i believe the ajax answer by @ManseUK is probably your best bet in terms of working direction, but regarding how the callback would help, the point is to put all the code you want to run AFTER the totals have been processed into the callback function. This isn't a javascript-specific thing. Basically, in your original code, you are calling the async function, and while it's off happily doing its thing, your next lines are executed. You really want those next lines to NOT execute until after the async call is finished.

Answer (score 0):

The callback function you pass to `onreadystatechange` is not `retrieveCategoryCount`. It's return value is lost because the function is only called in response to the readystatechange event.

Do what you need to do with the data **in the callback**. Don't try to return the data.